# How to iterate bigquery code on monthly basis?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, tableau-api

I want to iterate the below code with monthly basis, so that I can make a tableau dashboard for monthly data who went offline for each month:

```
SELECT
    Deal_ID,
    Category,
    MONTH(date),
    YEAR(date)
FROM [big-query-1233:BI_Automation.live_deals_history_since_15_sep] 
WHERE
    MONTH(date) = 4 AND
    Deal_ID NOT IN (
        SELECT Deal_id
        FROM [big-query-1233:BI_Automation.live_deals_history_since_15_sep]  
        WHERE MONTH(date) = 5
    )
```

Comment: Your group by aggregation makes no sense because you don't have any aggregate functions in your select clause.

Comment: yes, Thats a silly mistake

Comment: Maybe you should tell us what you are trying to do here.

Comment: In the above code, I figured out number of customers who went offline on May by comparing it with no. of customers in April, as you can see that in my code. I just want to loop the above code with monthly basis, so that I can check for each month separately.

Comment: @devpratim . . . You may see see how your code is related to some problem, but I certainly don't.  I would suggest that you ask another question, provide sample data, desired results, and explain what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and avoids using JOIN and rather uses Analytical Functions

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT
  Deal_ID, Category, 
  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM month) AS month,
  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM month) AS year  
FROM (
  SELECT
    Deal_ID, Category, month,
    LEAD(month) OVER(PARTITION BY Deal_ID, Category ORDER BY month) AS next_month
  FROM (
    SELECT
      Deal_ID, Category,
      DATE_TRUNC(DATE, MONTH) month
    FROM `big-query-1233.BI_Automation.live_deals_history_since_15_sep` 
    GROUP BY Deal_ID, Category, month
  )
)
WHERE DATE_DIFF(next_month, month, MONTH) > 1
-- ORDER BY month, Deal_ID, Category
```

You can test / play with it using below dummy data

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `big-query-1233.BI_Automation.live_deals_history_since_15_sep` AS (
  SELECT 1 AS Deal_ID, 1 AS Category, DATE '2017-01-01' AS DATE UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 1, DATE '2017-01-02' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 1, DATE '2017-02-02' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 1, DATE '2017-02-15' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 1, DATE '2017-03-15' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 1, DATE '2017-04-15' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 1, DATE '2017-06-15' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 1, DATE '2017-07-07' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 1, DATE '2017-08-22' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 1, DATE '2017-12-12' 
)
SELECT
  Deal_ID, Category, 
  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM month) AS month,
  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM month) AS year  
FROM (
  SELECT
    Deal_ID, Category, month,
    LEAD(month) OVER(PARTITION BY Deal_ID, Category ORDER BY month) AS next_month
  FROM (
    SELECT
      Deal_ID, Category,
      DATE_TRUNC(DATE, MONTH) month
    FROM `big-query-1233.BI_Automation.live_deals_history_since_15_sep` 
    GROUP BY Deal_ID, Category, month
  )
)
WHERE DATE_DIFF(next_month, month, MONTH) > 1
ORDER BY month, Deal_ID, Category
```

Note: it is not clear if you need COUNT of customers or just list of customers
Above gives you list
But if you need COUNTs - you just add extra GROUP BY and COUNT as it is below

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT
  Category, 
  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM month) AS month,
  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM month) AS year,  
  COUNT(Deal_ID) AS customers
FROM (
  SELECT
    Deal_ID, Category, month,
    LEAD(month) OVER(PARTITION BY Deal_ID, Category ORDER BY month) AS next_month
  FROM (
    SELECT
      Deal_ID, Category,
      DATE_TRUNC(DATE, MONTH) month
    FROM `big-query-1233.BI_Automation.live_deals_history_since_15_sep` 
    GROUP BY Deal_ID, Category, month
  )
)
WHERE DATE_DIFF(next_month, month, MONTH) > 1
GROUP BY month, year, Category
ORDER BY month, year, Category
```

Comment: I wasn't sure if it matters to the OP, but I was also worried about the query's behavior near the year boundary. One way to handle it with the analytic function solution would be to order by `year * 12 + month`.

Comment: even though i aliased it as a month within the inner selects, in reality it is still date truncated to month, so this is already taken care of here :o) - i was just a little lazy here to come with better namings :o)

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will help to get you started. Note that it uses standard SQL instead of legacy SQL with BigQuery:

```
SELECT
  Deal_ID,
  ‎Category,
  ‎EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date) AS month,
  ANY_VALUE(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date)) AS year
FROM `big-query-1233.BI_Automation.live_deals_history_since_15_sep` AS t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM `big-query-1233.BI_Automation.live_deals_history_since_15_sep` AS t2
  ‎WHERE
    t1.Deal_ID = t2.Deal_ID AND
    ‎DATE_ADD(DATE_TRUNC(t1.date, MONTH), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) =
  ‎    DATE_TRUNC(t2.date, MONTH)
)
GROUP BY Deal_ID, Category, month
ORDER BY month, Deal_ID;
```